# jQuery + - buttons don't input value as i expected

Tags: jquery, increment

I have an ajax module that updates prices on a website as customers change the quantity, or selected attributes they require. As soon as the value is entered in the input box the price is updated.
I decided to add some nice jQuery buttons to increment the value rather than the user having to click the box then type in the quantity.
The problem is that the script i use to create the buttons doesn't trigger the price change, even though it does change the value in the input field.

My script is:

```
<script language="javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#cartAdd").prepend('<div class="dec button">-</div>');
jQuery("#cartAdd").append('<div class="inc button">+</div>');
jQuery(".button").click(function() {
var $button = jQuery(this);
var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();

if ($button.text() == "+") {
var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
} else {
if (oldValue >= 1) {
var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
}
}
$button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
});
});
</script>
```

Is there any way that i can make this function so that the price updater recognises the new value in the input field?

Comment: click will work with only loaded DOM elements....as you are adding button later explicitly....So use "on" or "live"... live is deprecated
so use on if you are using latest jquery lib.

Comment: if you are creating button dynamically then use jquery `ON` or `bind` function.

Comment: what does your html look like?

Comment: view-source:http://bonnyes.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=2_14&products_id=24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use event delegation so you don't have to worry about 'live' and if you're looking for a change event to fire, you'll have to do it manually like Tetaxa said. Something like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var $cartAdd = jQuery('#cartAdd')
      , $quantity = $cartAdd.find('input')
      , $price = jQuery('#price');

    $cartAdd.prepend('<div class="dec button">-</div>');
    $cartAdd.append('<div class="inc button">+</div>');

    $cartAdd.click(function(evt) {
      var $incrementor = jQuery(evt.target)
        , quantity = parseInt($quantity.val(), 10);

      if($incrementor.hasClass('inc')) {
        quantity += 1;
      } else if($incrementor.hasClass('dec')) {
        quantity += -1;
      }

      if(quantity > 0) {
        $quantity.val(quantity).change();
      }
    });

    $quantity.change(updatePrice);

    function updatePrice() {
      var price = 15.50
        , quantity = parseInt($quantity.val(), 10);
      $price.text(quantity * price);
    }
  });

</script>
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H3dfJ/) with the working code.

Edit: I added some code that handles the change event on the quantity input.

Edit 2: I see what the issue is now. After looking through your source, it appears you are only looking for onkeyup on text inputs, so the triggering of change will not have any effect. To solve your immediate problem, I would substitute the above:

```
      if(quantity > 0) {
        $quantity.val(quantity).change();
      }
```

and instead put

```
      if(quantity > 0) {
        $quantity.val(quantity);
        xhr.getPrice();
      }
```

Comment: Blah. Instead of evt.trigger it should be evt.target. Sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry to upset you, but the value still won't increment. Now, where did i put that wall to bang my head against??

Comment: Check my last edit, this one works. Really, really sorry about this.

Comment: It does indeed work as far as incrementing the value is concerned, but it still doesn't cause the price updater to do it's job. :(

Comment: There is quite a bit of code for the price updater. I guess you can probably see the relevant java/ajax in the source though. "view-source:http://bonnyes.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=2_14&products_id=24"

Comment: Excellent. That works perfectly. Give the man a gold star and a beer :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use delegate function for elements that gets loaded after the page is loaded

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.button',function(){
 //Code here
});
```

Documentation for [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

```
try this 1...

    jQuery(".button").on('click',(function() {
    var $button = jQuery(this);
    var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();

    if ($button.text() == "+") {
    var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
    if (oldValue >= 1) {
    var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
    }
    }
    $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
    });
```

Comment: None of the options for using .on have resolved the issue. Scratching my head somewhat now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the value in the input field changed, but you have some event handler attached to the change event which is not triggered, is this correct? 
If so, change your code to this to trigger the event manually:

```
$button.parent().find("input").val(newVal).change();
```

Comment: Tried .change and no luck. I've posted a link to view source code in a n earlier comment.